# Load data dynamically on page scroll using jquery ajax in Yii Clistview

Tags: yii

How to Load data dynamically on page scroll using jquery ajax in Yii Clistview.I want it that like first 10 record display, and on scroll again query loaded and give next 10 records. every time query called and next 10 records display on scrolling of page.

Like This in core PHP "http://phppot.com/jquery/load-data-dynamically-on-page-scroll-using-jquery-ajax-and-php/".

Is Yii provide this type of facility???

Comment: not by default, but there are extensions for that matter

Comment: ohkk... i will try..